# ASP.NET Form Action Invalid Percent Encoding

Tags: asp.net, forms, iis, encoding, utf-8

I have a web application that places the user's search term in the query string, in a similar way to Google. E.g. the address might be `www.example.com/mysearchpage.aspx?q=searchTerm`.

Usually this works fine, but if there is a special character in the search term such as â, the `action` attribute on the form is encoded to percent encoding and the character is replaced with `%u00e2`.

If I search for `chât` I will end up with the URL `www.example.com/mysearchpage.aspx?q=chât`in the browser's address bar but the `action` attribute on the form that comes back from the server would be `www.example.com/mysearchpage.aspx?q=ch%u00e2t` which means that a subsequent form submission fails because the URL is incorrectly formatted.

I have ensured that in IIS the encoding is set to be UTF-8 for Requests, Response Headers and Responses. I have also inspected the page being delivered from IIS in Fiddler and that already includes the incorrectly encoded `action`.

The encoded format appears to be in a non-standard format as explained in this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Non-standard_implementations).

Is there a way to prevent IIS from encoding the form's `action` in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add `targetFramework=4.5.2` into the `httpRuntime` tag in the web.config file.

Previously this was not specified but was specified in the `compilation` tag, however specifying `targetFramework=4.5.1` still caused the problem.